# django cms placeholder not in structure view

Tags: django, django-cms

My co programmer developed a django plugin for use in a django project and on his setup, the plugin works. he can write a placeholder in the django template being used and load that with the custom plugin via the django-cms structure view. I tried doing the same thing but i noticed that the placeholder i put in the html in the same place he put it in isn't appearing in the structure view. the only placeholders appearing in the structure view and can be edited are static placeholders. placeholders entered like the ones in the django tutorial

http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.3.x/introduction/templates_placeholders.html

and are placed with this code

`{% placeholder "custom_name" %}`

aren't appearing in the structure view. i couldn't find a similar scenario here in stackoverflow. I have a fairly similar setup to my co programmer too. i copied the same repo he's working on and i even used a dump from his postgres database in case there's something wrong with my own setup but still no luck. there are no DEBUG errors appearing in the console or the webpage so I am out of ideas. Has anyone encountered a similar situation? The django-cms we are using is version 3.1.0.

Thanks

Comment: Hello @dogfish, please upgrade to djangoCMS >= 3.3.x.

Comment: hi @Paulo. i just figured out earlier what was wrong. The page i was testing was not a django-cms managed page which was why the placeholder wasn't working. Thank you for answering though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out earlier today what was wrong. I didn't notice immediately, that the page i was trying to edit was not a django-cms managed page which is why the placeholder wasn't working in it. In django-cms managed pages, the placeholder is working properly.

Thanks